# deserializeobject in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

Arrives data in json format for me that i can deserialize and work with the data in .net famework 4.0 but I want to know how Can I do it in .net 3.5?
as .net 3.5 does not support dynamic

Considering that the data in my Json can be differentin each call so I cannot make a class with all the info I need. as it is not fixed and varies each time

```
dynamic ParObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(context.Request["XXXX"]);

string v= paramsObj.v;
string y= paramsObj.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic overload `DeserializeObject<T>`. With this you can specify the type and you will get an object of this type insted of a dynamic.

See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm

```
public class ParObj
{
    public string v {get;set;}
    public string y {get;set;}
}

var paramObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParObj>(context.Request["XXXX"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, May I have with and example? it is a little confusing.

Comment: string  test= null;   
                test= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(context.Request["XXX"]);  .-----------Something like this
??